# Application pool security level SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

What are the Server-Level Roles that should be granted for the App Pool in a Web Application on SharePoint 2013?
bulkadmin,
dbcreator,
diskadmin,
processadmin,
public,
securityadmin,
serveradmin,
setupadmin,
sysadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL server roles for an application pool identity that connects to a content database are Public + SPDataAccess.  This is done automatically by SharePoint 2013 and you should not need to do it manually.  The details are found in this MS TechNet article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863(v=office.15).aspx